# Can Ontario university students apply for the "30% off Tuition" or any other significant grant offered by OSAP if they attend school outside Ontario?

Tags: canada, ontario, tuition, university

My daughter is on her way to Dalhousie this fall. I'm almost certain I read (a few months back) that she was eligible for the [Ontario 30%](http://www.ontario.ca/education-and-training/30-off-ontario-tuition) but now it appears as if she is not (maybe I originally mis-read?)

Tuition costs are crazy-expensive. Would love some help in any direction with respect to what we can apply for/are eligible for.

Her step-father and I have a combined household income of maybe $130K/yr and her father doesn't pay a cent in support and has little/no income to speak of. His gross income last year was $6K or something. We are a household of 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have originally mis-read, or the information you read was misleading and has since been corrected. Rather than the usual places, I went to look at the Ontario provincial budget, i.e. the "horse's mouth" on provincial money matters. (Actually, the budget implementation bill would have been more authoritative, but IANAL.)

Anyway, looks like the "30% Off Ontario Tuition grant", introduced at the beginning of 2012, does *not* apply if the student attends an institution outside of Ontario. It seems to have been that way since the outset.

Here's a portion of a page I grabbed from the [2012 Ontario Budget (PDF)](http://www.fin.gov.on.ca/en/budget/ontariobudgets/2012/papers_all.pdf):

[image: Page 16 from 2012 Ontario Budget with portion highlighted indicating that "for students enrolled in college diploma or certificate programs at publicly funded Ontario institutions"]

Notice the highlighted parts. In particular:

> [...] for students enrolled in college diploma or certificate programs at publicly funded **Ontario** institutions. [...]

Perhaps where confusion may have arisen: the 30% tuition grant is administered as part of OSAP (Ontario Student Assistance Program), and OSAP loans *are* available to students who attend post-secondary school outside of the province (at a qualified institution).